# Easiest way to open a window and draw a filled rect on it in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, draw

I tried pygame and tkinter, but both block the main thread with a while loop. There are some workarounds, but I think they are relatively complicated. In Java for example I can just create a JFrame add a JPanel to it and draw on the JPanel. This does not block the Thread the JFrame/JPanel was created on. Is there a key difference between Python and Java so that Python cannot do the same thing or did I just use the wrong packages or used them wrong?

Edit1:
Main Question: Easiest way to open a window and draw a filled rect on it in Python without blocking the main thread.

Edit2:

tkinter example:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 60, 60, fill='blue')
canvas.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()

print("I won't get printed until window is closed")
```

pygame example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 500
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

print("I won't get printed until window is closed")
```

what i want:

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self):
        ...  # create window that does not block main thread

    def draw_rect(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        ...  # draw rect on window

    def clear(self):
        ...  # clear window

canvas = Canvas()
canvas.draw_rect(10, 10, 60, 60, 'blue')
print('I get printed even while window is active')
```

Edit3:

what i want in Java:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.function.Consumer;

 public class Canvas {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // test the Canvas class
         Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500); // creates canvas window
         canvas.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200, Color.BLUE); // draws a rect
         canvas.clear(); // removes all drawings from canvas window
         canvas.fillRect(50, 100, 300, 200, Color.RED);
         canvas.fillRect(100,150,300,300, Color.CYAN);

         // everything here will be executed
     }

     private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     private List<Consumer<Graphics>> drawTasks = new ArrayList<>();

     public Canvas(int width, int height) {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
             @Override
             public void paint(Graphics g) {
                 super.paint(g);
                 for (Consumer<Graphics> drawTask : drawTasks) {
                     drawTask.accept(g);
                 }
             }
         };
         panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
         frame.add(panel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
     }

     public void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color){
         drawTasks.add(graphics -> {
             graphics.setColor(color);
             graphics.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
         });
         frame.repaint();
     }

     public void clear() {
         drawTasks.clear();
         frame.repaint();
     }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely the last option :)

Comment: Kinda hard to tell without seeing concrete code though.

Comment: What's your question, actually? Of course you can block the GUI thread in an graphical Java application if you want, the same way you don't have to block in your main loop in a pygame or tkinter application. This is not about languages, but GUI frameworks (well, pygame isn't even a framework). If you're creating e.g. a Swing application, there's still a main loop, but it's abstracted away from you so you don't have to think about drawing individual pixels to the screen or processing events in the event queue.

Comment: Could you give an example where you use tkinter, pygame, etc. and the main loop does not get blocked?

Comment: If you only need to draw once (no need for events) you could look into python's Pillow library.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of *and the main loop does not get blocked*? When using e.g. pygame, you write your main loop yourself, so it's up to you how to implement it. You mentioned Java in your question, but if you create a JFrame and show it, you also start a loop by calling `setVisible(true)`, which is also a blocking function. And I don't know what you expect to happend in your last code sample. Should the application create a window, then immediatly print the text and quit? There's no magic keeping your window open.

Comment: GUI programming is usually event driven: somewhere's a loop handling and dispatching events, which triggers other code to run. Do you actually have a specific problem to solve? Because the answer to *Easiest way to open a window and draw a filled rect on it in Python without blocking the main thread* is: don't create a loop. Create a window, draw something on it, and update the screen. But what's the point of this? Your program will reach the end and quit.

Comment: As far as I know setVisible(true) does not block. I know that there has to be an event loop, but I would like that it gets like you said abstracted away from me like in Java. When I tried to use pygame/tkinter I tried to move the event loop to another thread but both libaries don't seem to like that.

Comment: *As far as I know setVisible(true) does not block.* Yes, that's true, I was mixing it up with .NET's Application.Run. Thanks for you edits. I think I now understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your Java code, a seperate thread is created (the event dispatch thread) that handles the GUI for you. The equivalent in pygame would be something like this:

```
import pygame
import threading

class Canvas(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.start()

    def draw_rect(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, pygame.Color(color), (x, y, width, height))

    def clear(self):
        self.screen.fill((50, 50, 50))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                print(e)
                if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(60)

canvas = Canvas()
canvas.draw_rect(10, 10, 60, 60, 'blue')
print('I get printed even while window is active')
```

but, as you can see yourself if you run this code, it won't work because pygame's event system only works correctly when called from the main thread (at least on Windows. It works in Linux IIRC).

So what you're asking for is not reliable possible with pygame this way.

---

Using tkinter, you could use something like this:

```
import threading

class Canvas(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        import tkinter
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        s = tkinter.StringVar()
        s.set('Foo')
        f = tkinter.StringVar()
        f.set('Bar')
        tkinter.Label(root,textvariable=s).pack()
        tkinter.Button(root,textvariable=f).pack()
        root.mainloop()


app = Canvas()
print('I get printed even while window is active')
```

which will work but is a little bit hacky because the `tkinter` module has to be imported in the same thread in which you call `mainloop()`.

Comment: Do you think there is a libary that can achieve what I want?

Comment: @Felix You can use tkinter. I updated my answer. But, as I say in my answer, it feels a little bit dirty. Why exactly do you need this behaviour? Maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: Since I am coming coming from Java I think object orientated. I just like the thaught that I have this canvas.py file where I can create a Canvas object and call simple drawing operations on it. I really like the Java class I wrote. It is really good for beginners and I wish to have the same thing in Python, but maybe this is not suited for Python. I don't know..